# My Kendo grid is not populating with JSON object returned from Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am writing an MVC application that is storing certain information in session variables. I am able to populate a list I have in my repo class without a problem. The issue I am having is when I click on my search Client controller it just gives me a JSON object but does not populate my Kendo Grid.

This is my datasource:

```
var clientSearch = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "SearchClient",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"    
        },

        create: {
            url: "ClientInformation",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST"
        },
        parameterMap: function (data, operator) {
            if (operator != "read")
                return JSON.stringify(viewModel);
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "clientName", 
        }
    }
});
```

This is my Grid:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: clientSearch,
    columns: [{
        field: "clientName",
        title: "Client Name",            
    },
    {
        field: "clientNumber",
        title: "Client Number",
    },
    {
        field: "clientType",
        title: "Client Type",
    }]        
})
```

This is my controller that is returning my JSON object:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SearchClient()
{
    HttpSessionStateBase session = HttpContext.Session;
    Repo repo = new Repo(session);
    var result = repo.GetClient();

    return Json(new
    {
        list = result,
        count = result.Count
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: If you are using asp.net MVC, why don't you use razor to create your grid?

Comment: Our company is moving away from Razor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify your fields in the schema of data source object:

```
var clientSearch = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
    read: {
        url: "SearchClient",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"    
    },

    create: {
        url: "ClientInformation",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST"
    },
    parameterMap: function (data, operator) {
        if (operator != "read")
            return JSON.stringify(viewModel);
    }
},
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "clientName", 
        fields: {
            ID: { editable: false },
            clientName: { editable: false },
            clientNumber: { editable: false },
            clientType: { editable: false }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Bruno, I ran into this answer in other web posts

Answer (score 0):

Kendo.Mvc expects [DataSourceRequest and DataSourceResult](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/custom-binding) when binding grid as such:

```
public ActionResult SearchClient([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        HttpSessionStateBase session = HttpContext.Session;
        Repo repo = new Repo(session);
        var result = repo.GetClient();

        return Json(new
        {
            list = result.ToList().ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState)
        }, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);           
    }
```